Code Snippet for Add to Cart Redirect only works for the Add to Cart Button in SINGLE PRODUCT PAGE
The code snippet for redirecting the add to cart to the checkout page only works when I press the add to cart on the SINGLE PRODUCT PAGE. It does not work when I click the add to cart button on the SHOP PAGE of my woocommerce website.
Here is the code snippet that I am using. How do I change this so that when I click the add to cart button on the SHOP PAGE, it is also redirected to the CHECKOUT PAGE.
add_filter('add_to_cart_redirect', 'lw_add_to_cart_redirect');
function lw_add_to_cart_redirect() {
 global $woocommerce;
 $lw_redirect_checkout = $woocommerce->cart->get_checkout_url();
 return $lw_redirect_checkout;
}


Go to WooCommerce > Settings > Products > General and disable both options: “Redirect to the cart page after successful addition” & “Enable AJAX add to cart buttons on archives“:
